# Oracle NVL function not allows second parameter as datetime

Tags: oracle, datetime, nvl

```
select nvl(trunc(null),trunc(sysdate)) from dual;
```

While executing above query i am getting following error

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

look like when i take string or number instead of `trunc(sysdate)` it run fine.

Comment: `NVL()` needs to have similar datatypes as argument!

Comment: DId you just try `TRUNC(NVL(yourcolumn,SYSDATE))`.. That would be the clean solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/393139):

> The first parameter to NVL is determining the expected datatype of the
>   returned column, with the trunc function defaulting that to NUMBER
>   because it's parameter is NULL. The second parameter to NVL needs to
>   match that datatype which it doesn't because it is a date.

```
SQL> select nvl(trunc(sysdate), sysdate) as mydate from dual;

MYDATE
-------------------
26/05/2006 00:00:00

SQL> select nvl(trunc(null), sysdate) as mydate from dual;
select nvl(trunc(null), sysdate) as mydate from dual
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

or you can do like this:

```
SELECT NVL(TO_DATE(TRUNC(NULL)),SYSDATE) FROM dual;
```

Comment: In my real query i have a datetime parameter which returns null, `select nvl(trunc(pd_eftv_to),trunc(sysdate)) from dual;`

Comment: @RashminJaviya:- You can try like this: `select nvl(TO_DATE(trunc(pd_eftv_to)),TO_DATE(trunc(sysdate))) from dual;`

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter must be of the same datatype as the first parameter. The `trunc` function is overloaded. Apparently when you pass it a `null`, it interprets the value as a number and returns a number. Any of the following works:

```
SELECT NVL (NULL, TRUNC (SYSDATE)) FROM DUAL;

SELECT NVL (TRUNC (TO_DATE (NULL)), TRUNC (SYSDATE)) FROM DUAL;

SELECT NVL (TRUNC (CAST (NULL AS DATE)), TRUNC (SYSDATE)) FROM DUAL;
```

---

**Follow up:**

If the variable that is being used is properly defined as a date, then you should not have a problem. As an example, the following runs without error:

```
DECLARE
   FUNCTION f
      RETURN DATE IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN NULL;
   END f;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (NVL (TRUNC (f), TRUNC (SYSDATE)));
END;
```

In order to get an answer that actually solves your problem, I would recommend editing the question to include code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: In my real query i have a datetime parameter which returns null, `select nvl(trunc(pd_eftv_to),trunc(sysdate)) from dual;`